# How to convert a long table into a shorter/aggregate table? R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this table here

[image]

This is my desired goal

[image]

I've tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
table(data$Category, data$Amount)
```

Comment: Is the amount column just the amount from the data frame or are you wanting something else? if you just want to print the data frame then type the name.

Comment: `df %>% distinct(Amount, Category)`